# How can I write an XML string in Stax without duplicating namespaces

Tags: java, xml, stax

Part way through creating an XML file with Stax I have some XML in the form of a String. I write this to the Stax output using:

```
public void addInnerXml(String xml) throws TinyException {
    try {
        parent.adjustStack(this);

        XMLStreamReader2 sr = (XMLStreamReader2) ifact.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF8")));

        for (int type = sr.getEventType(); sr.hasNext(); type = sr.next()) {
            switch (type) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT:
                case XMLStreamConstants.DTD:
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                    continue;
            }
            parent.getWriter().copyEventFromReader(sr, false);
        }

        sr.close();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new TinyException("addInnerXml", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new TinyException("addInnerXml", e);
    }
}
```

It all works great except namespaces used in the passed in XML, that are defined in the root element, are duplicated again in the inner nodes. Note that the p prefix is repeated

> <p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
>   xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
>   xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
>     <p:cSld>         <p:spTree>           <p:pic
>   xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">

Is there a way to turn this off?

notes: XMLStreamReader2 implements org.codehaus.stax2.typed.TypedXMLStreamReader and is actually XMLStreamReader.
parent.getWriter() also returns an XMLStreamReader2.

thanks - dave

Comment: What is `XMLStreamReader2`? I cannot find it in the standard JDK library. And what class is returned by `parent.getWriter()`? Do you use the standard StaX implementation?

Comment: @vanje - I just updated with notes at the end. Thanks - dave